# Cannot find the drive with NOOBS files

Tags: raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ with a 32 GB Memory Card. I had to format it to FAT32 using the guiformat.exe shown on raspberrypi.org. I then extracted the NOOBS zipped folder into the SD card. I plugged my Raspberry Pi into a screen and turned it on, only to see a pop-up saying "**Cannot find the drive with NOOBS files**". Does anyone know what happened?

Comment: have you tried repeating the instructions - it's amazing how many times just doing everything from scratch fixes such issues

Comment: Possibly caused by the way the card was formatted. Use SD formatter, don't use guiformat (should not be necessary for 32GB card) and check it's FAT (not exFAT). Then put Noobs on the card again. See e.g. https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/issues/498

Comment: I can confirm, that is not really correctly formatted SD card. Do it with https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/eula_windows/.

Answer (score 1):

To quote from [a related issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/issues/467):

> This error can happen if your SD card has been formatted without a partition table.

As stated in [another related issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/issues/498):

> Without an MBR partition, you can only have a single 'partition' on the card, which means NOOBS wouldn't be able to create any new partitions to install any OSes onto

So it looks like the card has not been properly formatted.